# JS on IE8: Removing terminating comma still gives "Expected identifier, string or number"

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8, cross-browser

Testing my website on IE8 throws a strange error; I first thought it was due to leaving a comma after "class: 'deflect'", but it still complains about "Expected identifier, string or number":

```
    var deflector =
    jQuery('<div/>', {
        style: 'left: ' + x + 'px; top: ' + y + 'px',
        class: 'deflector'
    });
```

Cleared cache, no luck. What could that be?

(btw real browser don't complain about anything ;)

Comment: @ta.speot.is gotta prove yourself? Add value or keep your trolling to yourself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`class` is a [**reserved keyword** *<sup>[MDN]</sup>*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Reserved_Words). Use a string:

```
jQuery('<div/>', {
    style: 'left: ' + x + 'px; top: ' + y + 'px',
    'class': 'deflector'
});
```

At least Firefox (since FF5) will complain about this as well and with good reason.

Comment: Woah :) fast and straight to the point. Works! Wonderful. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Ok, let me rephrase that: At least Firefox (since FF5) will complain about this as well and with good reason. ;)

Comment: Ah ehe ok :) Was in a "legacy compatibility" mindset ;) Cheers